# Why has my flag been declined?

Tags: discussion, support, declined-flags

I flagged the question [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81656/3429430) for closure as it is a resource recommendation question. My flag has been declined.

Why is my flag declined? Isn't the question just a resource recommendation question?

A long time ago, I had asked a question on Stack Overflow and it was immediately closed as it did break the rules and policies of Stack Overflow. Are there different standards for popular(useful for the majority) questions? I may appear to be passive aggressive here, but the point is that every question should be treated equally. There shouldn't be any double standards.

Comment: See the first comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270231/c-standard-thread-marked-as-off-topic

Comment: It is a 6 year old question.  What was considered on topic back then was very different from today.  Retro-actively closing/deleting all of those old questions simply is not practical nor fair.  Google "rep-ocalypse" to find out more.

Comment: @HansPassant Old questions that are no longer on topic are closed all the time.  Less effort is spent to get them closed, but it's not wrong to close them or worth going out of the way to save them if they don't have particularly valuable content.  On what basis do you think that this question is close worthy?

Comment: @HansPassant What is the policy/rule of stackoverflow in this regard? Can the current policies be applied to the old posts or not?

Comment: @HansPassant Googling "rep-ocalypse" gives me some blog posts. Is there some faq/help-centre where the policy is mentioned.

Comment: It should also be pointed out that a moderator didn't decline this, the community did: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6510671 . I didn't know that the community could do this in review yet. Must be a recent change.

Comment: @BradLarson Can flags be handled by the community? Is it a 10k tool or something?

Comment: @user31782 - Close flags are only handled by the community in the close votes review queue. People vote based on that, and flags are accepted, disputed, and (now, apparently) declined as a result of that review. The questions may also be closed from that review queue by community votes.

Comment: " the point is that every question should be treated equally." - disagree, discretion should be applied and cases can be taken on a case by case basis. Mindless adherence to the letter of the law isn't beneficial.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I disagree with you. If a new user isn't allowed to ask for a resource recommendation question, then so should be the old users. Law Is Blind, cf. [Lady Justice](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/HK_Central_Statue_Square_Legislative_Council_Building_n_Themis_s.jpg).

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Asking for a *recommendation* as to what tool/external resource to use is off topic.

Asking a specific question about a specific resource (in this case the language specs) is not off topic.

Comment: Can I ask for a resource recommendation of some latest C language software.

Comment: @user31782  No..

Comment: @user31782 not if it will attract opinionated answers or spam.

Comment: @Compass The text in the help centre should be edited to: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow <strike> as </strike> **if** they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: @user31782 That's not a bad idea actually. Probably would be best for Meta to discuss that, though. In most cases, these questions attract opinion.

Comment: @user31782 The existing text is as it should be.  These types of questions are considered off topic because in the vast majority of cases they result in solely opinion based answers and spam.  It was considered worth losing the 1% of questions that don't have that problem to get rid of the other 99%.

Comment: @Servy Why not? I just need one software, currently I am using Dev-shed 5.2.0.0. It seems old. I need something that uses C11. How would it be opinion based? Either the software would support C11 or not.

Comment: @user31782 It would attract spam.  If you really just want to see any C11 program, go to that tag and look at questions until you find a working program; done.

Comment: Why does this have three downvotes. It's the truth.

Comment: @user31782 Ultimately, a question like what you described *might* be on-topic at [SoftwareRecommendation.SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but make sure you read the [guidance on asking question there](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @psubsee2003 thanks for telling about http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Boltclock The answer is trying to parse the reason it's still open incorrectly; in this case it's open because it's actively maintained and it's useful. For all intents and purposes, it's still asking for the location of an offsite-resource; which is ostensibly offtopic.  All that said, it shouldn't be closed. Perhaps wiki-locked, but not closed.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Why is that question off topic?  Asking for the location of an offsite resource is not off topic.  It's a specific, answerable question relevant to a programmer who is programming that has objectively correct answers.

Answer (score 29):

You're right. The question is off topic.

But you're also right that we don't treat all questions the same way.

Also, [we can't really compare it to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510004/what-problems-of-procedural-programming-does-oop-solve-in-practice). Apples and oranges.

We have a general rule that asking for off site resources (documentation: The original off site resource) is off topic. This is even present in the close reason:

> Questions asking us to recommend or **find** a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. (Emphasis mine)

So strictly speaking, this question is off topic.

But.

The C/C++ community has a history of wanting to keep these sorts of things around. [It happened with their book recommendation list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251665/when-should-old-list-of-x-questions-be-kept-as-wikis), and it happened here.

There are a few rules:

- The list **must be actively maintained**
- Where possible, we'll institute a wiki-lock
- The topic must be of sufficient quality to warrant keeping the question around ("What's your favorite programming cartoon" does not apply)
- You've got to want it.

In this case, the C/C++ community has continually shown that they're willing to put in the hard work to keep these sorts of things up to date.  That's why this question gets a pass.  You can't arbitrarily manufacture this sort of effort, it has to be a part of the community's identity. For the C/C++ community, this is (and continues to be) true.

It's also worth noting your flag was declined by the community -- not a diamond moderator. It's also been reviewed multiple times already: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6510671) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5676822) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/5629813) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5623414) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5586342).  There's quite a bit of community consensus around keeping this question open.

Comment: In short:  `Because C/C++` ;)

Comment: @user31782 I updated it to links to the actual reviews since regular users can't see that page. There are 9 reviews, but 4 of them got invalidated without any action due to close votes aging away, so I did not link those.