# How to locate community wikis?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I came across [When should old “list of X” questions be kept as wikis?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251665/when-should-old-list-of-x-questions-be-kept-as-wikis). On the page, there's a partial list of community wikis.

There does not appear to be a tag [community-wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/community-wiki) on Stack Overflow so that they can be easily found. For example, [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) only has the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) tags. And [Best C/C++ Network Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library) only uses [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [networking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/networking) tags

How does one locate community wikis?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily search through wiki questions using the `wiki:1` search operator. Combine it with other operators, like with `is:question` to find only community wiki questions.

Comment: Thanks animuson. 12,000+ wikis... Wow. I see I won't be able to read all of them (naively, that was my original intention). Perhaps a *community-wiki* tag could be created, and a process could tie the search *wiki:1 is:question* to the tag. I suggest it because I likely won't remember the trick in a couple months. And adding additional terms does not restrict results to wikis. For example, *"wiki:1 is:question c++"* and *"wiki:1 is:question AND c++"* returns non-wiki results.

Comment: @jww They shouldn't. I didn't see any in the ones I checked, but I did see non-wiki *answers*. Long time ago when it first existed, converting a question to CW didn't convert all its answers too.

Comment: Adding a meta tag to make them more searchable isn't really a great idea...