# Should I delete my question, which has been closed with an inappropriate reason?

Tags: support, specific-question, close-reasons, vote-to-delete

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Can you provide examples of a couple of elegant CMD/PowerShell/WSH Hybrid bash scripts (portable scripts)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73591618/can-you-provide-examples-of-a-couple-of-elegant-cmd-powershell-wsh-hybrid-bash-s)

I don't believe those who closed my question even properly read my question. At least, the reason given for closing doesn't seem appropriate. I was not asking for books or tools. The question was about writing scripts. Anyhow, I can delete the question. Should I?

Comment: You should have edited your original question not posted additional information as an answer

Comment: The question asks for examples and isn't properly scoped. See [Are list questions off topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139618/are-list-questions-off-topic) Instead of asking for examples you should simply ask something along the lines of: "How to write scripts that work in both CMD and bash?"

Comment: A lead for ***list of X*** questions: *[When should old "list of X" questions be kept as wikis?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251665/when-should-old-list-of-x-questions-be-kept-as-wikis)*. What is the canonical meta question? And/or [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)?

Comment: I have read your recent question and think that my reading was "proper", and I too find it to be off-topic for this site as it is very broad and is a type of question that invites forum-like discussions rather than a single best concise answer.  You may want to approach your meta concern differently and instead of assuming that your opinion on the site-appropriateness of your questions is correct, use meta as a place to discuss and learn what the community feels and why.

Comment: "I can delete the question." - While you can delete the question, if you delete the question, you still won't be able to ask the same question (at least without any improvements). So instead of resubmitting a question that will ultimately be closed for being a duplicate of a deleted question, you should **improve** your existing question and get it undeleted.  Of course the only reason it's deleted today, is because you choose to delete it, so I guess you ignored the communities advice about deleting it.

Comment: "What I have in mind is to try and write scripts that can be directly executed as is in two or more environments and perform ideally more or less similar tasks as appropriate under each environment." Then don't ask for *examples*; ask for *techniques*. Better yet: give a *specific* example of something you can do in (bat/bash), and ask how to make the script *also* work in `bash/bat`. That said, I don't think this is really a practical problem. Just write a separate script for each platform.

Answer (score 16):

I think the most relevant citation in the SO help center that corresponds to your question/answer is the first section of the [don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) page. The following paragraphs from that page, I think, accurately represent your question.

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.